# Need help in importing a .csv file to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

please ignore the echo calls, Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a self learner would appreciate any help

I am trying to import a .csv file to the sql database using php this is the code i have written so far and the connecting with the database is working fine, already checked that.

Please do ignore the echo call

```
   {if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if ($_FILES [myFile] [size] > 0) {
            $file = $_FILES [myFile] [tmp_name];
            $handle = fopen ( $file, "r" );
            $cnt = 0;
            do {
                if ($data [0]) {
                    $cnt += 1;
                    if ($cnt > 1) {
                        // for each question
                        $question_id = 0;
                        $quiz_id=0;
                        $qname=$_REQUEST["qname"];
                        $duration=$_REQUEST["qduration"];
                        $pts=$_REQUEST["qpts"];
                        $tag_id = 0;
                        $options = array ();
                        $options = split ( ";", $data [1] );
                        $correct = $data [2];
                        $chapter = $data [3];
                        $tags = $data [4];
                        $level = $data [5];
                        $tb = $data [6];
                        echo "INSERT INTO `quiz`(`name`, `duration`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `possible_points`, `status`, `location_id`) VALUES (.$qname.,.$duration.,now(),now(),.$pts.,'CREATED','')<br>";
                        echo "INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(" . $data [0] . ",1,1,null,now(),null,0,0)<br>";
                        echo "INSERT INTO `quiz_question`(`quiz_id`, `question_id`, `created_on`) VALUES (.$quiz_id.,.$question_id.,now())<br>";
                        foreach($options as $opt ) {
                            if($opt==$correct)
                            {
                            echo "INSERT INTO QUESTION_OPTION ('question_id','option','correct_flag') VALUES(".$question_id ."," .$opt.",1)<br>";
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "INSERT INTO QUESTION_OPTION ('question_id','option','correct_flag') VALUES(".$question_id ."," .$opt.",0)<br>";
                            }
                        }

                        echo "INSERT INTO tag(name) VALUES ('.$tags.')<br>";
                        echo "INSERT INTO `question_tag`(`question_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES (.$question_id.,.$tag_id.)<br>";
                        echo "---------------------------------------------------------<br>";
                    }
                }
            } while ( $data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, "|", "'" ) );
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var nameFlag=false;
      function checkQuizName()
      {
          var condt=$("#qname").val();
          if(condt==null || condt =='')
          {
              $("#available").hide();
              $("#notAvailable").hide();
          }
```

//Trying to import  a .csv file into my database this is my code so far and I am fairly new to coding

```
          else
              {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/quizapp_web_dev/services/CheckQuizName.php?qname="+condt,
                  data: "",
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if(data=="false")
                        {
                        $("#available").hide();
                        nameFlag=false;
                        $("#notAvailable").show();
                        }
                    else if(data=="true")
                        {
                        $("#available").show();
                        nameFlag=true;
                        $("#notAvailable").hide();
                        }
                  },
                 error: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("error"+data);
                }
              });
              }
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Enter Quiz Details</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    role="form">
                    <label>Upload Quiz :</label> Quiz Name:<input type="text" id="qname"
                        name="qname" onchange="checkQuizName()" /> <span id="notAvailable"
                        style="color: red; display: none;"
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Duration:<input
                        type="text" id="qduration" name="qduration" size="5" /> Points:<input
                        type="text" id="qpts" name="qpts" size="5" /> <input type="file"
                        id="myFile" name="myFile" /> <input type="submit" id="uploadBtn"
                        name="uploadBtn" value="Upload" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>} //Please ignore the echo calls, i am trying to import a csv file to the database
```

Comment: Be very careful, you are vulnerable to SQL injections! Be very careful

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. We don't need to see any extraneous HTML/CSS, or lines of code that should be ignored. We need to see the minimal code required to reproduce the problem, and we need a better description from you of _what the problem actually is._

Comment: Your AJAX call is not sending any information to your PHP script... But since I don't know what the problem is I can't confirm it

Comment: You try to use `$data`, but you don't define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import your csv file.

You may need to move your uploaded file to a temporal path in order to load it ( you can use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function in order to do this)